# Problema color mobile

Tags: css, mobile, iphone

Já não é a primeira vez que me acontece isso, e é um erro que me incomoda muito, mesmo sendo um pouco insignificante:

Algumas vezes percebo que a cor das fontes não são aplicadas no iphone, testei em dois e não são aplicadas. No android eu testei e funcionou, no mac também funcionou corretamente.

Se verificarem o "X" é branco mas no iphone não se aplica a cor.

Normalmente uso o safari no iphone, mas testei no chrome e também não funcionou.

Caso não tenha ficado claro por favor perguntem.

[Código](https://codepen.io/lucas-granvilla-da-silva/pen/YBbYKR#anon-login)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou `color: #ffffff !important` cor com 6 dígitos? Tb pode tentar desa forma e ver se resolve... `-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   -webkit-opacity: 1; `

Comment: Cara outra coisa que reparei, de onde vc tirou esse `X` ele não parece um caractere comum, ele parece um unicode ✗ ou emoji ✖ ❌ ✖️!!

Comment: Com 6 dígitos testei também.
Sobre o X realmente pode ser que não funcione porque não é fonte, boa ideia, é bem provável que seja isso.

Sobre as cores não funcionar eu dei uma pesquisada no assunto e no iphone acontece bastante quando é telefone. Vou testar colocando outro caractere.

Comment: isso mesmo hugocsl. Era um emoji. Problema resolvido. As outras vezes que me aconteceu provável que foi com telefone.

Comment: Posso postar como resposta? aí vc pode marca-la e a pergunta fica como resolvida pode ser?

Comment: Pode sim. Sobre a outra resposta que você deu sobre paginação no owl carousel ainda não consegui testar no código mas vou marcar como resposta também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que me parece esse caractere que vc está usando não é uma fonte comum e sim um `emoji`, por isso vc não consegue trocar a cor dele pelo `color` no CSS. Tanto que se vc trocar esse caractere por um `X` normal de texto deve dar certo e ele vai pegar o `color` setado no `style`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao que me parece esse X é na verdade o `Heavy Multiplication X` ✖️ e cada OS vai renderiza-lo como o padrão do sistema, conforme tabela abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem uma fonte com as características desse caractere e mais detalhes: https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/540/symbols/heavy-multiplication-x